# PHP: Persisting LDAP connection across requests

Tags: php, session, encryption, ldap

I have a (I think not so uncommon) scenario:

my PHP app queries an LDAP server to handle authentication. The LDAP server only accepts authenticated access, so the first ldap_bind() call is actually used as the authentication mechanism and to retrieve the logged in user's basic information.

So far so good. But when I want to use the LDAP service to perform other queries (e.g. the logged in user's or other users' extra info) I have to go through LDAP authentication again.

I *do not* want to store the user's password in session because it might leak, but I can't have the user authenticate at each request either in order to provide the credentials for the LDAP server.

So I thought about the following solutions:

1. Store the LDAP connection handle in session, so I don't have to provide credentials every time. That won't work because the handle is a resource and can't be serialized for session storage.
2. Store the password in session, but encrypted. The encryption seed could be derived from some volatile var, e.g. a hash of the session ID, so that it won't be stored in a var and can never leak.
3. `<Your idea here>`

Any thoughts?

Thanks

gm

Answer (score 1):

My two cents... First use case I think could be avoided pulling down everything for the user the first time you connect.  Store all of it minus the password in session.  Second case: Do you need to authenticate as user X to access that data?  Can you not create a user with read access and use those credentials (App user) to query these types of things.  Alternately maybe that user info should not live in AD.  Use it for authentication but keep user data in the DB (master), or synced in DB from AD (slave).

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the LDAP server.

You're right about the first case, but the most important use is to get other users' information, so that can't be cached.

Comment: If that is the case have you looked at adding [RADIUS](http://freeradius.org/) into the mix?  There may be some existing solutions using [EAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) that  will alleviate your concerns about keeping the password safe in the application.  ref: http://freeradius.org/features/eap.html

Answer (score 0):

As for storing the password, this is working (using Yii framework, but it's easy to adapt to vanilla PHP):

```
public function getUserPW(){
    if(empty(Yii::app()->user->sneak)) return false;

    $seed=sha1(Yii::app()->session->sessionID);
    $iv=substr(md5(Yii::app()->session->sessionID),0,16);

    return openssl_decrypt(Yii::app()->user->sneak,self::CRYPT_ALGO,$seed,false,$iv);
}

public function setUserPW($pw){
    $seed=sha1(Yii::app()->session->sessionID);
    $iv=substr(md5(Yii::app()->session->sessionID),0,16);

    Yii::app()->user->setState('sneak',
        openssl_encrypt($pw,self::CRYPT_ALGO,$seed,false,$iv)
    );
}
```